# Problem trying to import inet data type in datagrip

Tags: postgresql, import, inet, datagrip

When trying to use datagrip's csv import

I get this error for all records

[image: "17:623: conversion failed: "183.177.122.20" to inet (ip_address)"]

the csv I'm importing is data from an identical table in another database

[image]

Are there any things I can tweak to getover this issue?

Comment: It seems that the database cannot convert string to INET type. You need to learn how to make this conversion. Perhaps you can make this field TEXT and make the conversion by uour own then.

Comment: Please show the source row from CSV with the values and how they are quoted.

Comment: At the moment there are couple issues about network data types https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-15614/Can-t-import-network-address-types-via-CSV and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-15615/Can-t-remove-row-with-macaddr8-data-type . But, inet values inside CSV have to be quoted, e.g. `1, '192.168.100.128/25', '192.168.1.1', '08:00:2b:01:02:03', '08:00:2b:01:02:03:04:05'
`

Comment: Sorry I'm reviving this, but why would they *need* to be quoted? Unless I'm missing something, they don't contain the ',' character. And even if they do, only these could be quoted, just like a string field would be, right?